# Gd Library Image Style imagettftext

Tags: php, gd

How to make Like This Image?
I just want to learn how do i get output like this using GD library,
Thanks for your help guys..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```php
header('Content-Type: image/png'); // setting the content-type

$file   = "yourimage.png";
$image  = imagecreatefrompng($file); // creating the image
$font   = "YourFont.ttf";
$size   = 15; //pixels
$color  = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); //white color
$text   = "Your text here"

imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 20, 40, $color, $font, $code); // adding the text

imagepng($image); // outputting the image
```

For more see [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

**EDIT**: An example of using multiple `imagettftext()`:

```php
header('Content-Type: image/png'); // setting the content-type

$file   = "yourimage.png";
$image  = imagecreatefrompng($file); // creating the image
$font   = "YourFont.ttf";
$size   = 15; //pixels
$color  = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); //white color
$text       = "Your text here"

imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 20, 40, $color, $font, $code); // adding the text

$text = "Text 2";
imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 25, 45, $color, $font, $code); // adding the text

$text = "Text 3";
imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 30, 50, $color, $font, $code); // adding the text

imagepng($image); // outputting the image
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer:
Here's what i mean how i can set the meaning of every letter..
Sample

R - Relax
O - Obedient
B - Bright 

Like in the image.. thanks..

Comment: @RobRayo just use `imagettftext` multiple times.

Comment: @RobRayo See the example. Use `imagettftext` as many as you want, just change the position, text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, you could easily find it on google tho.

```
<?php
    header ("Content-type: image/png");
    $string = "your text"; // Change this text
    $font = 4; // try changing this as well
    $width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string) ;
    $height = imagefontheight($font) ;
    $im = imagecreatefrompng("/path/to/yourimagefile");
    $x = imagesx($im) - $width ;
    $y = imagesy($im) - $height;
    $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);
    imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y,  $string, $textColor);
    imagepng($im);
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I know That Function.. How can i detect every letter of the name and each meaning of the letter,,

Comment: That is not about the GD library, you should parse the name in PHP and get a word for every letter from your database. So you should have a database for letters and meanings. like C-> Clever S->Stupid etc. When your parse the name you will query every letter for their meaning.